# Some css.style edits are not showing in IE, FF and Chrome (but are in Safari)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

My recent edits of some styles in css.style (a, h3 and .fee_note) are not showing in IE, FF and Chrome (but they are fine in Safari).

In the test system, the edits did show OK, but each time I uploaded a page (any page), the css changes would be over-written. In the live system, the edits are ignored altogether.

The site is http://www.se1dentalcentre.co.uk/

Very grateful for an answer.

Comment: cacheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: As @JohnB said, delete browser cache and check whether the problem still persist or not.

Comment: Hello - the edits are three added or altered styles, a, h3 and .fee_note.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache but it makes no difference. Thank you.

Comment: h3 (seen on Index) should be normal weight and underlined: h3 {
 font-size:11px;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: normal;
 } and links should be blue, not grey: a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#0083CC;
 font-weight:bold; and .fee_note (seen on Our Fees page) should be blue, italic: .fee_note{
 color:#0083CC;
 font-style:italic;

Comment: Hello - I'm still struggling with this. Weirdly, one of my clients can view the edits and the other can't. They are both using IE. This - I suppose - would suggest that it is a cache problem, but unless I'm doing it wrong, clearing it makes no difference!